# Prove that this function is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, probability, expected-value

Let $g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ with $g(0) = 0$.

Let's start by assuming that there exists positive constants $\Gamma_-\leq 1 \leq \Gamma_+$ such that

$$\Gamma_- \leq g(k)-g(k-1)\leq \Gamma_+.$$

For $\phi \in \mathbb{R_+}$, consider a random variable $X_\phi$ that assumes natural values ​​with the following distribution:

$$ \mathbb{P}( X_\phi =k) = \frac{1}{Z(\phi)}\frac{\phi^k}{g(k)!} \text{, for all } k \in \mathbb{N}, $$

where $g(k)!=g(k)g(k-1)\cdot \cdot \cdot g(1)$, $g(0)!=1$ and $Z(\phi)$ is a normalizing constant given by
\begin{equation}
Z(\phi)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\phi^k}{g(k)!}.
\end{equation}

I need to show that the expectation of this random variable is a increasing function of $\phi$.

Denoting this expectation by $R(\phi)$, a simple calculation shows that

$$R(\phi)= \frac{1}{Z(\phi)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k\phi^k}{g(k)!} = \phi \frac{Z^\prime(\phi)}{Z(\phi)}.$$

By deriving this expression, we get

$$R'(\phi)= \frac{Z'(\phi)Z(\phi)+\phi Z''(\phi)Z(\phi)-\phi Z'(\phi)^2}{Z(\phi)^2}.$$

So we just need to show that the numerator of the above expression is positive. But I fail to show this.

We can also see that $R(\phi)= \phi \frac{d}{d \phi} \ln Z(\phi)$, but I don't know if it helps either.

Any help in solving this exercise will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Hint, for $\phi_1 < \phi_2$, try applying Jensen's inequality with the convex $f(x) = x(\phi_2 / \phi_1)^x$ applied to $X_{\phi_1}$ and see what you get.

Comment: @JairTaylor this is a statement from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.07907.pdf. See page 6.

Comment: I will use your hint. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I can provide a more detailed answer later, or if you are able to figure it out you can answer your own question.

Comment: If it is possible to give a more detailed answer, I would appreciate it. I'm really having a hard time with this.

Comment: Hmm, I actually couldn't get the idea to work out the way I wanted. Maybe I'll think about it more later.

Comment: No problem. Thanks!